# Suggestions for implementing a drag and drop feature

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a Battleships game which I've decided to do with AngularJS. At the moment I'm struggling with finding a way for the user to place the ships on the board using a drag and drop feature.

The board itself is a directive of size 10x10 ( a 2d array of objects, as a design imagine a chess board in which every square is an object with properties ). The available ships to be placed would be DOM elements of different sizes ( squares ).

What I'm trying to achieve is, lets say I drag a ship of size 5, drop it on the board, and for all the squares on which the ship has been dropped will change a property within the object. So if all squares at first had a property like `isOccupied = false` when I drop the ship the property would be set to `true` only for those 5 particular squares.

Is there a way this can be achieved ? Or maybe an alternative.

I've tried looking into the HTML Drag & Drop API but I dont think it helps with the particular outcome I'm looking for.

A pretty good example of what I'm reffering to, tho' in this case the ships have already been placed on the board. https://battleship-game.org/en/

Comment: Whoops, I misunderstood your question. Apologies for my unhelpful answer.